# Recursive Formula For Probability Proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

I am solving a probability question and I have come across a recursive formula that is hard to prove. The recursive formula goes like this:
$$a_1=2$$
$$a_n = a_{(n-1)} + a_{(n-2)} + ... + a_{(n-k)},\;\;\;\;n\geq k+1$$

where $n$ is the number of flips of a fair coin and $k$ stands for successive $k$ heads. The term $a_n$ stands for the number of ways of flipping a coin $n$ times without getting $k$ successive heads.

Now I want to prove that $a_n \leq c^n$ for some $c<2$, and $n\geq (k+1)$.

I thought about proving by induction but you reach the induction hypothesis and things get hairy from there. Is there any other method to prove this?

Comment: Two questions: 1. With "for some $c<2$" do you mean "for every $c<2$"? and 2. May I assume $c\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: yes meant to put for all. I should change that. And yes cER, c just has to be some positive constant.

Comment: ((On a related note, you still did not explain why the number $a_n$ of words in the alphabet $\{h,t\}$ avoiding the subword $h^k$ solves the recursion $a_n=a_{n-1}+\cdots+a_{n-k}$ for $n\geqslant k+1$.))

Comment: You told me it was a question that has to do with recursive sequences so I decided to just make a post about recursive sequences. The proof is simple when k=2. When k=2, a_1 gives 2, as it is impossible to have two heads. Thus when the first flip gives T, you need the rest of a_n to contain a sequence that does not give any successive 2 heads. This will give you a_n-1. If the first flip gives H, we move onto the second flip. So when the second flip gives H or T, we exclude the chance that the second flip gives H as the hypothesis is false. So the second flip must be a T.

Comment: If the second flip is a T, we have HT, and thus need a sequence of a_n-2 to follow, thus a_n = a_n-1 + a_n-2. I just generalized it without proof as the question assumes us to do so.